# Habitat as fixed factor with a nested design

Tags: r, mixed-model, nested-data, ecology

I have the following design:

Two regions, in each region 6 sites, in each site three habitats and in each habitat 4 100m2 plots. Then, in each site 12 plots (3 habitats, 4 plots). For each site I sampled three different habitats, which are the same in each site. Plots are nested in sites which are nested in regions.

My doubt is about habitat. I think it's a fixed factor and crossed (?) with the nested factors.

I set the following model. Is it right? Should it be in another way?

```
fit <- lmer((Index) ~ Habitat + (1 + Habitat|Region/Site/Plot100), my.data)
```

Comment: You use different terms in the first couple sentences. Are the "plots" the same as the "habitats"? Are the "localities" the same as the "sites"? Can you clarify this?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the questions. Sites = localities

Comment: I gather that the "plots" are in the "sites", & the "habitats" are in the "sites"; are the "plots" the same as the "habitats"? If not, what is the relationship between them? Can you define these terms? What is your response (`Index`)?

Comment: The plots are in the sites. In every site I sampled the three same type of habitat so I guess habitat should not be considered as a nested level, because each habitat type is shared in all sites. Sites are different beaches along the coast; habitat, types of dunes (embryo, shifting and fixed dune). For each type of dune (habitat) I sampled 4 100m2 plots, then 12 in each site (3 habitats, 4 plots). Index are different functional diversity indeces calculated for each plot. Sorry again, the post was confussing because I mixed plots in habitat and plots in site. Thank you for patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plots nested within sites and sites nested within regions, so you could could specify the right side of the random effects formula as `|Region/Site/Plot100`.

The same Habitat occurs in each plot, therefore it is *not* nested within plot and could be included as a fixed effect. If the association between `Habitat` and the outcome is expected to vary between different levels of plot/site/region then you could include `Habitat` as a random coefficient: `(Habitat|Region/Site/Plot100)`

Note that this involves a large number of random effects to estimate so over-fitting and model identification could be an issue depending on the number of observations you have.

However, you have only 2 regions, so this gives a strong argument for not including it as a grouping variable, but as a fixed effect instead. So a better model would be:

`fit <- lmer((Index) ~ Region + Habitat + (1 + Habitat|Site/Plot100), my.data)`

or

`fit <- lmer((Index) ~ Region + Habitat + (1|Site/Plot100), my.data)`